# How to execute screen with a fixed process id?

Tags: screen

How can i run an app on ubuntu 12.04 64 bit, with screen with non changing ID.

So. if I run a program in screen, it got an unique ID like 3353.
and if I run more apps in screen, i need this ID to return the app's console.

I will run an app with non changing ID, because if I stop the app, and I start it again, its got a new id.

Some ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can give your screen session a name of your choice with the option `-S`. For example

```
screen -S myname
```

The name you give will then show in `screen -ls`. You can also use it when resuming the session, `screen -r myname`.